# How to use sleep function in Python to wait for 10 minutes and check again and run the script?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, sleep

We have scheduled a cron job to start 5 Elastic Clusters at 7:30 AM, and we have to another cron job scheduled to start a script in spark cluster at 8:00 AM.

In order to run the script in spark cluster, The 5 elastic clusters status should be green. Currently, I am monitoring the ES clusters, if all 5 clusters are not green, i am disabling the cronjob to run the script in spark cluster.

I have defined the below methods to find ES clusters status and to find out the count of how many ES clusters are green.

I am using the below logic to check if all(5) ES clusters are green trigger the function if not exit.

```
def get_es_clusters_status(elastic_load_balancer)
def count_green_es_clusters(es_clusters_status)
es_clusters_status = get_es_clusters_status(lb_instances)
green_es_clusters_count=count_green_es_clusters(es_clusters_status)
    print(green_es_clusters_count)
    if green_es_clusters_count == 5:
        print("YES There are 5 green clusters")
            script_in_spark()
            else:
                 print(" Not all 5 clusters are green exiting....")
                 sys.exit(1)
```

But I would like to use sleep functionality from time module and wait for 10 minutes and check the Green ES clusters count again if they are 5 trigger the function otherwise wait for 10 more minutes. Unless there are 5 ES clusters i should not trigger the script in spark cluster.

Comment: please reformat your code with proper indentation and syntax. you have two function def's but neither have ':' marks.  the indentation is downright unreadable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your problem is fairly simple. You can use an `if else` statement to check if all Clusters are green, and in the else section do the sleep. Here is what the `if else` statement would look like:

```
while clusters!=green:
    time.sleep(600) #This sleeps for 600 seconds, which is 10 minutes. 
    if clusters==green:
        break  #The last 2 lines are not needed but are a foolproof way to make sure your code breaks.
```

Make sure you import time at the top of your code.